# Scala JMX without traits

Tags: scala, jmx

I am adding some instrumentation into our Scala application, and ran into an issue:
When using JMX in a standard, OO way, declaring the MBean as a trait, and have my class implement this bean, everything works perfectly. 
However, my goal is to try to just have my class annotated as a bean (MBean or MXBean) and not have to write the interface. The reason for this is that I want to say something like

```
val foo = new Counter with JMX...
```

where JMX is a trait that registers foo as attribute of my class.

is this possible? the JMX validator is looking for a class with an interface and complains if I don't create one, is there a way to add some form of it at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have a parallel hierarchies of JMX interfaces and classes.  E.g. if you had several JMX MBeans with common methods you could have a base interface with the common abstract methods and then a partial implementation which you could mix in to the MBeans. Would this solve your problem?  I did it once and it was only a tad tricky.  You just have to rigidly observe matching name in same package rule.